# SQL to MongoDB Migration using nodejs script

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

Im new to nodejs and Im currently doing an sql to mongodb migration. I have created a script to load data to mongodb from sql queries. I created the script with the sample code from Google and it is working. But im facing below issue and need a workaround for this.

I have an sql query array and I don't need to run those queries if any of the queries has any syntax issues or any errors in the query result. (Say if the second query has syntax issue then no need to load the data of first query to mongo, currently its loading in my case). Basically if any of the query has any issue then no need to load the result in the mongo collection. And also if any issues from the mongo side no need to commit the transactions.

I have used the mongo transactions here to roll back the data if any errors. please find the below code and any help would be much appreciated.The sql and mongo credentials are mock data only.

config file code

```
  var mongoCollection = 'collectionName';
  exports.mongoCollection = mongoCollection;

var queryList = [
'sample query one',
'sample query two ' 
];
exports.queryList = queryList;
```

main script code

```
  var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
  var sql = require('mysql');

  const config = require('./assets/config');

var sqlConfig = {
user: 'username',
password: 'password',
server: 'servername',
database: 'databasename',
port: 'portname',
multipleStatements: true
};

async function transaction() {
  const mongodbUrl = 'mongourl';
   const client = await MongoClient.connect(mongodbUrl, {useNewUrlParser: true}, {useUnifiedTopology: 
true});
 const db = client.db();

config.queryList.forEach(query => {
    new sql.ConnectionPool(sqlConfig).connect().then(pool => {
        return pool.request().query(query)
    }).then(result => {
        (async()=>{
            const session = client.startSession();
            session.startSession({
                readConcers: {level: 'snapshot'},
                writeConcern: {w: 'majority'}
            });
            try {
                const collection = client.db('mongodbName').collection(config.mongoCollection);
                await collection.insertMany(result.recordset, {session});
                await session.commitTransaction();
                session.emdSession();
                console.log('transaction completed');
            }catch(error){
                await session.abortTransaction();
                session.endSession();
                console.log('transaction aborted');
                throw error;
            }
        });
        sql.close();
    }).catch(error => {
        sql.close();
        throw error;
    })
});
};

transaction();
```

Comment: Request to kindly update the code if I did any mistakes

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the volume of data, you might look at breaking the process into two parts

- Get the data from mySql
- If no errors, load into Mongo

That would save you having to roll back the mongo writes

You can also take advantage of the [default mongo pool size (5)](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.6/api/global.html#MongoClientOptions) and use pool on the mySQL side too.
Currently, this code is creating a pool for every select, which isn't optimal

```
config.queryList.forEach(query => {
    new sql.ConnectionPool(sqlConfig).connect().then(pool => {//<-New pool per query?
        return pool.request().query(query)
    })
})
```

Instead, you can set up a pool once, [per the mySql documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql#pooling-connections)

It looks like that driver only has a callback api, but you can promisfy the query to make it easier to work with.

So to put it all together, you could try something like this (this isn't working/tested code, just a suggestion)

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var sql = require('mysql');

const config = require('./assets/config');

var pool  = sql.createPool({
  connectionLimit : 5,
  host            : 'servername',
  user            : 'username',
  password        : 'password',
  database        : 'databasename'
});

async function transaction() {
  try{
    const mongodbUrl = 'mongourl';
    const client = await MongoClient.connect(mongodbUrl, {useNewUrlParser: true}, {useUnifiedTopology: true});
    const db = client.db();
    const collection = client.db('mongodbName').collection(config.mongoCollection);

    //Map your query list to an array of runSql promises
    //this will complete when all queries return, and jump to the catch if any fail
    let results = await Promise.all(config.queryList.map(runSql))
    
    //Map the results to an array of mongo inserts
    let inserts = await Promise.all(results.map(r=>collection.insertMany(r.recordset)))
    
    //Close all connections
    pool.end((err)=>err?console.err(err):console.log('MySQL Closed'))
    client.close((err)=>err?console.err(err):console.log('MongoDB Closed'))
  }
  catch(err){
    console.error(err)
  }
};

transaction();

function runSql(queryStr){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
        pool.query(queryStr, function (error, results, fields){
            error?reject(error):resolve(results)
        })  
    })
}
```

If data volume is a concern, you might want to look at [getting streams from your mySql selects](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql#streaming-query-rows) instead of just running them